# how to change setmode(board) t setmode(bcm)

Tags: python, devise, raspberry-pi3, iot, sensors

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.Board)

ControlPin = [16,18,22,29]

for pin in ControlPin:
    GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(pin,0)

seq =[
[1,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0],
[1,1,0,0],
[0,1,0,0],
[0,1,1,0],
[0,0,1,0],
[0,0,1,1],
[0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0],
[1,1,0,0],
[0,1,0,0],
[0,1,1,0],
[0,0,1,0],
[0,0,1,1],
[0,0,0,1],
]


for i in range(512):
    for halfstep in range(16):
        for pin in range(4):
            GPIO.output(ControlPin[pin], seq[halfstep][pin])
        time.sleep(0.001)
```

1.currently able function with board mode,but not able with bcm mode,but i want to use bcm mode, what part of code need to change to make bcm mode work...........................

Comment: Try reading the documentation: https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage/

Answer (score 0):

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

PIN = 17

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(PIN, GPIO.OUT)
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading. From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_